# Not printing proper value of "key.data" in Berkeley DB using C

Tags: c, berkeley-db

I am new to Berkeley DB and learning using online guide. Now i have the following code below:

```
DB *dbp;
DBT key, data;
int ret, t_ret;
int k = 1;

key.data = &(k);
key.size = sizeof(k);
memset(&key, 0, sizeof(key));

if ((ret = dbp->put(dbp, NULL, &key, &data, 0)) == 0)
{
    printf("db: %d: key stored.\n", (char*)key.data);
}
```

Now the printf statement, instead of returning value "1", is returning something else. Don't know where I am going wrong.

Comment: I suggest you look for tutorials on using that API (for ex http://cxwangyi.wordpress.com/2010/10/10/how-to-use-berkeley-db/). The code you have here does not make any sense (hint: you're not setting data, you're clearing `key` after having set it up, you're casting what you thought you set to an `int` to a `char*` and printing it as an `int`...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since key.data is a void*, you need to dereference it to get the value. Try:

```
printf("db: %d: key stored.\n", *(int*)key.data);
```